# Answer appears in Stack Exchange Android app but not website

Tags: bug, android-app

I recently installed the Stack Exchange app on my Android phone-- Nexus 4, Android 4.4.3-- and I've noticed that an answer supplied for one of my SO questions appears in the app, but not on the main website and I'm curious if anyone is aware of this issue? I searched the site and did not find any reports of other users experiencing a similar issue. Note that I first viewed the answer in the app after receiving an alert. Just wanted to make it known.

Comment: Do you have a link to the question?

Comment: Yes, the question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23485527/jquery-scroll-down-for-more-content-arrow *edit: now I'm not even seeing the answer on the app, although it was there the other day... very confused now...

Comment: My guess would be that the answer was perhaps in a review before displaying state (e.g. first post from new user) and not shown on the site whereas the app doesn't take that into account and shows it regardless. If so the answer not appearing on wither would suggest it failed to pass review. Only a guess though; I don't have the rep to view deleted and removed posts. Was it a poor quality answer?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there was an app for Stack Exchange. Looked for a Stack Overflow one, couldn't find any and dropped the issue ...

Comment: Thanks for your response, indivisible. That would totally make sense-- although the answer was actually helpful (it referenced an approach that I had ultimately found myself.) However, at the time I didn't actually accept or upvote the response as I just read it quickly on my phone while in transit. Interesting that it seems to have totally disappeared at this point. Also, Catalin, I think the app is pretty phenomenal for managing all Stack Exchange accounts.